# ¿Invocar un componente desde el envento onClick React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un componente que al hacer clic a un botón, debería llamar a otro componente. En la función le asigno un valor como boletoElegido donde esta el id (auque si uso props.deberia poder devolver el objeto entero)

Este es el código fuente del componente que manda llamar al nuevo.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState} from 'react';
import BoletoDetalles from './BoletosDetalles';

function SeleccionBoleto({boletos})
{
    const [boletoElegido, guardarBoletoElegido] = useState();

    const seleccionarBoleto = e => {
        guardarBoletoElegido(e.target.value);
    }

    const enviarBoletoElegido = () =>{
        return <BoletoDetalles boletoElegido = {boletoElegido}/>;
    }


    return(
        <Fragment>
            <p>Seleccion de ticket a evaluar</p>
            <form>
                <select onChange={seleccionarBoleto}>
                    <option value=""> Seleccione el ticket a evaluar</option>
                    {
                        boletos.map(boleto =>(
                            <option key={boleto.id} value={boleto.id}>{boleto.id}</option>
                        ))
                    }
                </select>

                <div>
                    <button type="reset" id="btn_limpiar" className="btn btn-danger col-sm-6">Limpiar</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-info col-sm-6"
                        onClick={enviarBoletoElegido}
                    >Buscar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default SeleccionBoleto;
```

En mi onClick, uso una función que devuelve el componente, pero no lo carga en el DOM.

El contenido del otro componente por ahora es un texto de prueba para comprobar si funciona la carga del nuevo componente.

Answer (score 0):

Has considerado usar react-router? Seria una opcion.
Otra opcion seria que tengas ambos componentes dentro de tu Fragment, pero el componente que quieres que se muestre al dar click estaria oculto dependiendo el state, tal ve

```
const [visibilidad, setVisibilidad] = useState(false)
```

y al dar click en lugar de tratar de mostrar el componentet solo cambias el state, en tu Fragment validas de que si el state visibilidad es true muestras el componente.

```
{visibilidad ? <Component />: null}
```

Comment: Si, aunque pensaba usar eso en otra parte de la aplicación, esto lo hago para validar información y que no se pierda el usuario. El operador ternario funciona si son 2, pero aquí son más de 2, por eso mejor separé esa lógica antes del return en una variable y esa variable se carga como componente al inicio de app.js